# Webpack4: how to deal with images in subfolders

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

My images separated in different subfolders in src/images directory. When i run creating build with webpack all images are copied to one img folder and images with same name just replace one another.This is my webpack configuration for images:

```
 {
     test: /\.(png|jpe?g)/i,
     use: [
        {
           loader: "url-loader",
           options: {
              name: "img/[name].[ext]",
              limit: 10000
            }
         },
         {
            loader: "img-loader",
            options: {
                name: "img/[path]/[name].[ext]",
                useRelativePath: true
            }
         }
     ]
 }
```

Can you please suggest how to configure webpack to separate images using the same folder structure as in src/images.  I am new to webpack. Thank you

---

**So here is the final answer that works for me:**

```
{
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g)/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "url-loader",
                            options: {
                                name: "img/[path][name].[ext]",
                                context: "src/assets/images",
                                limit: 10000
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "img-loader",
                            options: {
                                name: "img/[path][name].[ext]",
                                context: "src/assets/images"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What You're in code is asking Webpack to handle image files with:

```
loader: "url-loader",
options: {
    name: "img/[name].[ext]",
    limit: 10000
}
```

which means put all the files in `img/[name].[ext]` fashion(which puts all the files in a single directory 'img'), where as you want to use `"img/[path]/[name].[ext]"` to be able to maintain the path structure of original files.

So, change your code block to this:

```
{
test: /\.(png|jpe?g)/i,
use: [
    {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
            name: "img/[path]/[name].[ext]",
            limit: 10000
        }
    },
    {
        loader: "img-loader",
        options: {
            name: "img/[path]/[name].[ext]",
            useRelativePath: true
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Optionally if the directory structure have too many levels, you can use something like:

```
options: {
    name: "img/[path]/[name].[ext]",
    context: "src" // or whatever common directories above actual images
}
```

Comment: I actually tried to use [path], but it takes the full path, so it put files in `img/src/assets/images/subfolder` instead of just `img/subfolder`

Comment: @Anna yes this is what it is supposed to do originally. You can try `context: 'src/assets'` under options to construct it the way you are looking for.

Comment: @Anna also updated my answer accordingly, please upvote and accept answer if this helps.

Comment: Happy to help :)